# valgrind on server process

Tags: valgrind, traffic

hi i am new to valgrind. I know how to run valgrind on executable files from command line. But how do you run valgrind on server processes like apache/myqld/traffic server etc ..

I want to run valgrind on traffic server (http://incubator.apache.org/projects/trafficserver.html) to detect some memory leaks taking place in the plugin I have written.

Any suggestions ?

thanks,
pigol

Answer (score 5):

You have to start the server under Valgrind's control.  Simply take the server's normal start command, and prepend it with `valgrind`.

Valgrind will attach to every process your main "server" process spawns.  When each thread or process ends, Valgrind will output its analysis, so I'd recommend piping that to a file (not sure if it comes out on stderr or stdout.)

If your usual start command is `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld`, start the server instead with `valgrind /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld`.

If you usually start the service with a script (like `/etc/init.d/mysql start`) you'll probably need to look inside the script for the actual command the script executes, and run that instead of the script.

Don't forget to pass the `--leak-check=full` option to valgrind to get the memory leak report.